# Replace first occurrence in each column with bash

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, replace

My input look like this (tab delimited file)

```
CHROM POS ID REF ALT 76_BRS_AMC_00D2282 c21_BE_MS1038U_BE_MS1038U_c30 93_BRS_MST_DNA17_53119M 94_BRS_MST_DNA17_53120M 100_BRS_BRU_D14_0867
01 12153 rs2454 A G 1,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,0
01 12154 rs2455 C G 1,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,0
```

And I would like a "#" instead of the first "_" in each column name

```
CHROM POS ID REF ALT 76#BRS_AMC_00D2282 c21#BE_MS1038U_BE_MS1038U_c30 93#BRS_MST_DNA17_53119M 94#BRS_MST_DNA17_53120M 100#BRS_BRU_D14_0867
01 12153 rs2454 A G 1,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,0
01 12154 rs2455 C G 1,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,0
```

I don't know how to handle tabulations with sed, I tried with awk

```
awk -F "\t" '/_/ && count < 2 {gsub("_","#");count++} {print $0}'
```

But it just replace all "_" and not just the first occurrence

I would like a awk or sed solution.

(Sorry if it's a replicated question, I did not find the answer)

Comment: how to handle tabulations with sed? as with awk: `\t`

Comment: Yes, I was looking in sed for the same as `^` to say "start of the word" but with tab separator instead of new line, where as I could have use actually `\t`but it was just a part of my issue. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sub` will replace the first occurrence, so just limit the records to edit to `NR==1`, loop each column in it, replace with the `sub` and `print` the rest as-is:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)sub(/_/,"#",$i)}1' file
CHROM POS ID REF ALT 76#BRS_AMC_00D2282 c21#BE_MS1038U_BE_MS1038U_c30 93#BRS_MST_DNA17_53119M 94#BRS_MST_DNA17_53120M 100#BRS_BRU_D14_0867
01 12153 rs2454 A G 1,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,0
01 12154 rs2455 C G 1,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,0
```

(You probably need to define `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}`, if you want the output to be tab-delimited also. Explained:

```
$ awk '
#BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}       # incase you want output tab-delimited also (not in above script)
NR==1 {                  # process the header record only
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)   # loop every column header
        sub(/_/,"#",$i)  # replace the first _ with #
}1' file                 # output
```

Comment: This only does the first column containing an underscore instead of the first underscore in each column

Comment: My bad. It needs a loop around it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this gnu sed

```
sed -E '1s/(\t?[^\t_]+)_([^\t]+)/\1#\2/g' infile
```

**Explain :**

-E use extended regular expression

1 operate only on line 1

the RE (\t?[^\t_]+)_([^\t]+) catch each column

(\t?[^\t_]+) catch the group 1

\t? starting with a optional tab (optional for the first column)

[^\t_]+ followed by at least 1 char which is not tab or _

followed by _

followed by another group

([^\t]+) catch the group 2

all chars which are not tab

\1#\2 replace the column by group1 followed by # followed by group2

g means operate on each column.

Comment: If you explain in detail each part of your expression I may could understand why it doesn't work (does not replace underscore) if my row start with `76_BRS_AMC_00D2282` instead of `CHROM POS ID REF ALT`. But your solution works for my precise case.

Comment: @Elysire I update my answer and it's ok now for the first column.